# Given dx/dt=AX, how do I use an exponential matrix to get a general solution to the following?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, dynamical-systems

A=[2 0 -1;0 2 0;-1 0 2]

A=[1 2 -1;2 1 1;-1 0 2]

I have diagonlised the first and arrived at a reasonable answer using PDP^-1, however trying to diagonalise the second matrix gets crazy messy. There's go to be a better way.

Comment: You have two different $A$'s, you have $x$ and then you have $X$. What is the task here, can you clarify? general solution to your diff eq?

Comment: I need to use an exponential matrix method to find a general solution for (primarily)             A=[1 2 -1;2 1 1;-1 0 2]. There are two parts to the question, represented by the two A values, but the seconond one is causing me the most trouble.